# Dynamically select charts in excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, togglebutton

I have an excel 2007 workbook that has multiple charts based on 3 critera (Account, Reason, and Factory).  Each of these reasons is split into 2 views (one by $ and one by %) so I have 6 tabs that each contain 8 charts (for a total of 32 charts).  In the interest of improving user experience, I would like to combine all of these charts on one tab.  Basically, I want to have the existing structure while adding two controls.  The first control would toggle all of the charts to show by either $ or %.  The second control would toggle between Account, Reason, and Factory views.  I have looked around the interwebs and haven't found anything on this.  Any ideas?  I have a file that I can share, but don't see an attachment button.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  My preferred way of doing this is to separate the charted data from the actual data.  Once this is done, you just need to create the functions that use the controls to pull in the data.  Here is one approach that could be modified for your example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023591/is-it-possible-to-get-an-excel-chart-with-possibility-to-select-the-graphs-to-di/30080511#30080511

Comment: Thank you, Byron, for the idea.  In my situation, my Y axis can be either 'Account', 'Reason', or 'Factory'.  The values of my X axis will change depending on which Y axis needs to be used.  What I'm looking for is a way that the user can select the Y axis values as well as the x axis values.  If you know of a way to upload a file, I would be happy to show you.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's the same idea, you create a column of data for the x and y axes based off a drop down, or cell, or something other user selectable item.  Then you build a formula that looks up the right data based on the selector.  If you want to upload a file, people generally add a link to a file sharing site and add it to the post.  I generally don't open Excel files off the internet though.